# sqlite porter "plugin_not_installed" on xcode

Tags: angularjs, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

xcode returns this error when I run my app in device (iPhone 6):

> WARN: Install the SQLitePorter plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add
>   uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter' ERROR:
>   plugin_not_installed

Answer (score 0):

run this

```
ionic cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter
npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite-porter
```

and in app.module.ts

```
import { SQLitePorter } from '@ionic-native/sqlite-porter';

providers: [
  SQLitePorter 
]
```